# expected comma error in rectangular data format for panel

Tags: panel, winbugs

I'm estimating following Panel data model from WINBUGS :

```
model   {
for(i in 1:N){ for (t in 1:T) {
y[i,t]~dnorm(mu[i,t],tau)
mu[i,t]<-
beta1*x1[i,t]+
beta2*x2[i,t]+
beta3*x3[i,t]+
alpha[pid[i]]}}
for(i in 1:N){alpha[pid[i]]~dnorm(alphabar,phi)}
alphabar~dnorm(0.0,0.0001) 
beta1~dnorm(0.0,0.0001) 
beta2~dnorm(0.0,0.0001) 
beta3~dnorm(0.0,0.0001)
tau~dgamma(0.01,0.01) 
phi~dgamma(0.01,0.01) 
}
```

and when I try to load data in rectangular format an error message shows up: expected comma (cursor next to y[]) :

```
pid[]   y[] x1[]    x2[]    x3[]
1   9.593559871 0   -0.443597636    6.88096801
1   8.633731008 0   -0.633257473    6.538920646
1   8.116118432 0   -0.858906415    6.375164245
1   9.255409335 0   -0.724801311    6.52249918
1   NA  0   NA  NA
```

---

```
15  NA  13.11252312 NA  NA
15  13.72839263 13.04181471 -0.724336386    7.109578571
15  13.62554546 13.24040771 -0.707439066    7.198946524
15  13.86061298 13.32195495 -0.705991918    7.212687311
END
```

How can I fix the error?

Please help!